# Django toolbar: not showing the results for query with filter with greater than

Tags: django

I have a simple query in Django. I have Django toolbar installed to check the SQL queries and the corresponding data

My model:

```
class RecipePosition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,help_text="If left blank will be same as Ingredient name Eg: Tomato pulp")
    mass_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=10,null=True,blank=True,default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

I have the below django query with filter.

```
RecipePosition.objects.all().filter(mass_quantity__gt = 0)
```

Django gets all the objects whose mass_quantity is greater than 0.

But when i check the sql in the django - toolbar. it shows:

```
SELECT "recipes_recipeposition"."id", 
       "recipes_recipeposition"."name",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."title", 
       "recipes_recipeposition"."updated", 
       "recipes_recipeposition"."timestamp" 
FROM   "recipes_recipeposition" 
WHERE  "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity" > 'Decimal(''0'')' 
ORDER  BY "recipes_recipeposition"."sequence_number" ASC
```

[image]

I tried this command in sqlite browser also, but it didn't show any results.

Why django-toolbar is not showing the correct SQL?

As per me the sql should be:

```
SELECT "recipes_recipeposition"."id", 
       "recipes_recipeposition"."name", 
       "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."title", 
       "recipes_recipeposition"."updated", 
       "recipes_recipeposition"."timestamp" 
FROM   "recipes_recipeposition" 
WHERE  "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity" > 0 
ORDER  BY "recipes_recipeposition"."sequence_number" ASC
```

and this when tested in sqlite browser shows the results.

Also when I tested this on shell_plus with `--print-sql --ipython` shows

```
$ python manage.py shell_plus --print-sql --ipython
System check identified some issues:

# Shell Plus Model Imports
from recipes.models import Recipe, RecipePosition

Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  5 2018, 02:35:40) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: RecipePosition.objects.all().filter(mass_quantity__gt=0)
Out[1]: SELECT "recipes_recipeposition"."id",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."name",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."title",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."updated",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."timestamp"
  FROM "recipes_recipeposition"
 WHERE "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity" > '0'
 ORDER BY "recipes_recipeposition"."sequence_number" ASC
 LIMIT 21
```

Only on django-toolbar it shows Decimal() thing here on Django shell it shows `WHERE "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity" > '0'`

I also tried [debugsqlshell](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commands.html#debugsqlshell) as mentioned in the django-toolbar documentation. Its shows `"recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity" > '0'` rather than `"recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity" > 'Decimal(''0'')'`

```
$ python manage.py debugsqlshell                   
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  5 2018, 02:35:40) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [2]: from recipes.models import Recipe, RecipePosition

In [3]: RecipePosition.objects.all().filter(mass_quantity__gt = 0)
Out[3]: SELECT "recipes_recipeposition"."id",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."name",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."title",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."updated",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."timestamp"
FROM "recipes_recipeposition"
WHERE "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity" > '0'
ORDER BY "recipes_recipeposition"."sequence_number" ASC
LIMIT 21 [1.58ms]
```

I dont know why django-toobar is using `"recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity" > 'Decimal(''0'')'` instead of `"recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity" > '0'`

I want to rely on django-toolbar, but now i am worried.

Comment: What field (`DecimalField` or `IntegerField`) you used to construct `mass_quantity`

Comment: please see the update question. It shows fine in shell_plus, the way i expected, only in django-toolbar it shows Decimal() thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lot of struggle and going through the code. I did the following changes in the source code and then everything worked the way i want.

```
####################
http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.css
# By doing this the sql will show in multiple lines with indent

#djDebug .djDebugSql {
    #word-break:break-word;
    z-index:100000002;
}

#####################

# replace \n with <br> and space with nbsp and dont use Boldkeyword
# By doing this the sql will show in multiple lines with indent

def reformat_sql(sql):
    stack = sqlparse.engine.FilterStack()
    options = formatter.validate_options({'reindent':True,'indent_width':True,})
    stack = formatter.build_filter_stack(stack, options)
    #stack.preprocess.append(BoldKeywordFilter())  # add our custom filter 
    stack.postprocess.append(sqlparse.filters.SerializerUnicode())  # tokens -> strings
    #return swap_fields(''.join(stack.run(sql)))
    return swap_fields(''.join(stack.run(sql)).replace("\n", "<br/>").replace(" ", "&nbsp;"))


#####################

in file  /lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py
# because of this the greater than 0 is shown as deciman(0.0)   
# change for decimal wrap p in rev_typecast_decimal

def _record(self, method, sql, params):
    start_time = time()
    try:
        return method(sql, params)
    finally:
        stop_time = time()
        duration = (stop_time - start_time) * 1000
        if dt_settings.get_config()['ENABLE_STACKTRACES']:
            stacktrace = tidy_stacktrace(reversed(get_stack()))
        else:
            stacktrace = []
        _params = ''
        try:
            _params = json.dumps([self._decode(rev_typecast_decimal(p)) for p in params])
            #_params = json.dumps([self._decode(p) for p in params])  I  


###########################


            hare = []
            if params is not None:
                hare = [self._decode(rev_typecast_decimal(p)) for p in params]
                try:
                    _params = json.dumps([self._decode(rev_typecast_decimal(p)) for p in params])
                   # _params = json.dumps([self._decode(p) for p in params])
                except Exception:
                    pass  # object not JSON serializable

            template_info = get_template_info()

            alias = getattr(self.db, 'alias', 'default')
            conn = self.db.connection
            vendor = getattr(conn, 'vendor', 'unknown')

            params1 = {
                'vendor': vendor,
                'alias': alias,
                # 'sql': self.db.ops.last_executed_query(
                #     self.cursor, sql, self._quote_params(params)),
                'sql': self.db.ops.last_executed_query(
                     self.cursor, sql, hare),
                'duration': duration,
                'raw_sql': sql,
                'params': _params,
                'stacktrace': stacktrace,
                'start_time': start_time,
                'stop_time': stop_time,
                'is_slow': duration > dt_settings.get_config()['SQL_WARNING_THRESHOLD'],
                'is_select': sql.lower().strip().startswith('select'),
                'template_info': template_info,
            }




################################################
```

The final out put looks like, with decimal(0.0) replaces with 0 and well formatted sql

```
SELECT "recipes_recipeposition"."id",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."name",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."recipe_id",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."ingredient_id",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."recipeposition_slug",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."cooking_unit",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_unit_id",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."volume_unit_id",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."volume_quantity",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."pieces_unit_id",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."pieces_quantity",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."cooking_notes",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."sequence_number",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."title",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."updated",
       "recipes_recipeposition"."timestamp",
       "ingredients_ingredient"."rate" AS "ingredient__rate",
       CASE
           WHEN "ingredients_ingredient"."munit" = 'kg' THEN 'kg'
           WHEN "ingredients_ingredient"."munit" = 'ltr' THEN 'ltr'
           WHEN "ingredients_ingredient"."munit" = 'pcs' THEN 'pcs'
           ELSE 'False'
       END AS "ingredient__cost_unit",
       CASE
           WHEN "ingredients_ingredient"."munit" = 'kg' THEN CASE
                                                                 WHEN ("recipes_recipeposition"."mass_unit_id" IS NOT NULL
                                                                       AND "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity" IS NOT NULL
                                                                       AND "recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity" > '0') THEN CAST(("recipes_recipeposition"."mass_quantity" * "single_measurements_singlemeasurements"."quantity") AS NUMERIC)
                                                                 ELSE 'False'
                                                             END
           WHEN "ingredients_ingredient"."munit" = 'ltr' THEN 'ltr'
           WHEN "ingredients_ingredient"."munit" = 'pcs' THEN 'pcs'
           ELSE 'False'
       END AS "reciposition_cost_quantity"
FROM "recipes_recipeposition"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "ingredients_ingredient" ON ("recipes_recipeposition"."ingredient_id" = "ingredients_ingredient"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "single_measurements_singlemeasurements" ON ("recipes_recipeposition"."mass_unit_id" = "single_measurements_singlemeasurements"."id")
WHERE "recipes_recipeposition"."recipe_id" = '1'
ORDER BY "recipes_recipeposition"."sequence_number" ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Good news, I think you need to make the most minute of changes!

Instead of:

```
RecipePosition.objects.all().filter(mass_quantity__gt = 0)
```

You require:

```
RecipePosition.objects.all().filter(mass_quantity__gt=0.0)
```

Comment: It does not make any difference

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi What happens if you were to use my amended example?

Comment: The problem is now with the syntax, the problem lies in the django-toolbar.

Comment: Can you please provide error traces so I can help you debug.

Comment: I just found that its showing something wrong results.